# Are there Core Data call back methods?

Tags: core-data, ios4, notifications

I am wondering if there is any special way to take action when something happens in a core data entity.

Here what I mean in  the present case. I have a file name stored as an attribute in a core data entity.

As the app is running, it can happen that the item with this file name is removed from core data.

In that case what I want to happen is that the file gets removed from the file system.
And this is my question:
Do I need to write my own code to perform this removal?
Or is there a way, that I could use, so a removal procedure would be fired automatically when the item is removed from core data?

In other words, is there a call back method like:

```
-(void) objectWillBeRemoved:((NSManagedObject*))object
```

or:

```
-(void) objectHasBeenRemoved:((NSManagedObject*))object
```

Thanks for any relevant tip.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. 
You can read about it in [NSManagedObjectContext Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html).

Answer (score -1):

`NSManagedObject#willSave` and `NSManagedObject#didSave` should do what you want. [See apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/willSave)