# how to know managedObjectContext is getting changed in another view controller

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am following the tutorial for core data at here. We have RootViewcontroller and addRecipeViewController.

I list some classes and some functions and a screen for the flow below so that you wont get lost

---

```
Recipe.h
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface Recipes :  NSManagedObject  
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * recipeName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * cookingTime;

@end
```

---

```
addRecipeViewController.h
@class Recipes;

@interface AddRecipeViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    Recipes *recipes;
    UITextField *textFieldOne;
    UITextField *textFieldTwo;
}
```

---

```
addRecipeViewController.m
    - (void)save {
        1.recipes.recipeName = textFieldOne.text;
        2.recipes.cookingTime = textFieldTwo.text;
        3.NSError *error = nil;
        4.if (![recipes.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Handle error
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);  // Fail
        }   
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

---

RootViewController.m

```
- (void)insertNewObject {
    AddRecipeViewController *addRecipeView = [[AddRecipeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddRecipeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    Recipes *recipes = (Recipes *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recipes" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    addRecipeView.recipes = recipes;
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: addRecipeView];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [addRecipeView release];
}
```

---

picture for flow :
[image]

---

When event `Save` of  addRecipeViewController is clicked, it will save `recipes` into  `managedObjectContext`. Sooner or later, the rootViewConroller will retrieve data from `managedObjectContext` by using `NSFetchedResultsController`

**QUESTION**:  I dont understand how `manageObjectContext` is the same for all view controller so that you will get the most updated `manageObjectContext` at `rootViewController` after adding or deleting `Recipe` from `manageObjectContext` in `addRecipeViewController`

Please help me to understand this problem.

All comments are welcomed here.

Answer (score 1):

The managedObjectContext is basically your persistence layer and it includes a cache and a way to retrieve objects that are not yet in the cache. You want to avoid having multiple managed object contexts in your app so you don't need to deal with nasty cache synchronization issues.

So I'm not sure what problem you are running into exactly that is causing you to pause, but please don't over complicate the problem. Core Data is nice enough to provide you with a single entry point to the persistence store and keeps everything synchronized for you so you should run with it :)

Also, be sure not to confused `NSManagedObjectContext` and `NSManagedObject`. Managed objects live within the context. They are not the same thing.

Comment: my problem is when saving Recipe, which managedObjectContext will store this object and when you retrieve data ( obviously, data is Recipe object ), which managedObjectContext is used to do that...

Comment: It's all the same object. Your app should only need to have one single managedObjectContext. Store it in your AppDelegate for example and provide a method to get a hold of it from wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get notification when something changes in your context. If so, read this: [Are there Core Data call back methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771811/are-there-core-data-call-back-methods/10772908#10772908)